# Is it possible to spoof a service running on a port in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ports, kali-linux, spoofing

I was looking into the idea of port spoofing, and I came across [this](https://github.com/drk1wi/portspoof)
GitHub repository. I'm mainly looking to disguise my computer as something else, whereas this program opens *every* TCP port and emulates a service on it. Could I use something similar to say, only emulate a printer service?

Comment: Yes, just pull out the code from the repo and create your own script.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible to...?" should prompt the inverse question "What is stopping me from ...?"

And in this case: Nothing.

You can set up your system to accept a TCP handshake on every port and perform some sort of printing service, without actually printing anything.

Tools like nmap can't tell whether or not there is really anything printing - only that the program behind acts like printing service.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Is there a method of setting this up you would recommend? I've tried searching for something to work like this but kept ending back to that same repository.

Comment: @sketch54 tcp-wrappers is a good way to start